# iBatis using annotation - SQL query logging

Tags: logging, ibatis, mybatis

How to log SQL query while using iBatis with annotation.

```
public interface a {
  @Select(select * from tableName where id=#{id})
  public tablePojo getObject(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

How can I log what query iBatis is executing when `id` value is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to activate the logs for the `java.sql` package.**

After you do that, you'll get the queries, parameters and rows in your logs.

If you are using Log4j for logging you could add something like this in the `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=fatal, consoleAppender

log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG, consoleAppender

log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy\tHH:mm:ss}\t%C\t%p\t%m%n
```

You could also add a logger for `org.apache.ibatis` and see other additional stuff in the console:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis=DEBUG, consoleAppender
```

Answer (score 1):

If ure using maven, you need to add the "JAVA.UTIL.LOGGING" underlying SLF4J on maven, plus configure java logging [logging.properties](http://rbeltrand.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/java-logging-logger-y-netbeans-configuracion/), because mybatis dependency use by deafault the slf4j

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```